# Selenium c# buggy translation class

Tags: c#, selenium

I've written a class to do automatic translations with selenium. I'm working with it for two months now but unfortunatly it is so buggy that it isn't acceptable to work with. I get "frame detached errors" at line 27 And errors at line 33 that the element isn't found.

What i tried:

- tried adding Try & catch in to the code
- added thread.wait to give the website some time to reload.
- added a while loop to wait until element is available.

I've absolutly no idea what goes wrong after trying all of this. I've written other classes and they worked perfeclty. Any help appreciated!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebscraperBasic
{
    [Serializable]
    public class vertalenNu
    {
        public static String translateText(IWebDriver driver, String text, String languageSource, String languageDestination)
        {
            // nl - en - de - fr -es -it
            driver.Url = "https://www.vertalen.nu/zinnen/";
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("vertaaltxt")).SendKeys(text);
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            SelectElement testt = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("tselectfrom")));
            testt.SelectByValue(languageSource);

            SelectElement test = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("tselectto")));
            test.SelectByValue(languageDestination);
            

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@title='Vertaal']")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            String technicalSheettext;
            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("resulttxt")).Text != "");

                IWebElement technicalSheet = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("mt-translation-content"));
                technicalSheettext = technicalSheet.Text;
            }
            catch
            {
                technicalSheettext = "translation failed";
            }
            

            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();

            return technicalSheettext;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, there's no line numbers in your posted code. Could you please reference the lines and the full errors?  It's easy to copy and paste code and miss blank lines which could cause people investigating the wrong issues.   -

Comment: Ca  you please provide some test data too and more context on any options on how you're creating your driver?  Running your code as provided works fine for me: A vanilla driver`var driver = new ChromeDriver();` & running data: `translateText(driver, "hello world", "en", "nl");`   -  I would suggest you give it longer than 6 seconds to run the translation. get rid of `Thread.Sleep(3000);` and make the webdriver wait more like `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`  - this last one waits UP TO 30 seonds but continues when ready

Comment: There is a `<frame>` or `<iframe>` in the page. You need to switch to that frame using `driver.SwitchTo(...)` or `driver.Windows.SwitchTo(...)`. I forget the specific method call.

Comment: Can you also add a representative example of the HTML?